# Read XML into SQL tables in SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I want to read an XML file and split the data into a parent and 2 child tables.  Here is what the SQL schema where the data will go and the XSD.  I'm thinking SSIS is what I want to use but not sure how to go about it.  Should i iterate through the children and then insert the rows using code.  Any ideas would be helpful.  I am willing to use something other than SSIS.  I using MS SQL Server 2008.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MonthlyReportForm">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportingDate" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportingYear" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReportingRegion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TeamMembersName" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chkTraining" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chkVernacularMaterials" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RDHelpText" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chkOutOfCountryForm" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TravelData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TravelRowLocation" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TravelRowTeam" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TravelRowThisMonth" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TravelRowNextMonth" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainingReport">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TrainingData">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainerName" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TraineeGender" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TraineeAge" type="xs:decimal" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TraineeLanguage" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TraineeEducation" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TraineeProvince" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainingPrepHrs" type="xs:decimal" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainingTrainHrs" type="xs:decimal" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainingArea" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TrainingActivity" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]

Comment: Post the XML schema as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: My approach is always: Use SSIS to load the data into staging tables, then orchestrate SQL commands to get it where it needs to be. All of the XML examples I have seen in SSIS actually use database methods to shred the XML, not SSIS.